# Best IP to Country Database

Tags: geolocation, country, ip-geolocation, maxmind

We've got a requirement in a couple of our systems to detect a user's country based on their IP address. We'd prefer to use a database rather than a Web Service (to prevent issues with downtime/network access to an externally hosted service) so I'm looking for recommendations, anyone got any good or bad stories of the various IP to Country databases?

What I've found from google:

**Paid**

- [Maxmind](http://www.maxmind.com/en/country) - $50, then $12 a month, site license
- [IP2Location](http://www.ip2location.com/databases/db1-ip-country) - $50 a year, single server
- [software77](http://software77.net/geo-ip/) (Donationware)

**Free**

- [Maxmind Geolite](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/)
- [ip2nation](http://www.ip2nation.com/)

Any information on how the free ones compare to the paid ones would be good. Right now I'm leaning towards Maxmind's paid service since it includes automatic updates that we can run via script once a week.

Comment: You can also consider IP2Location LITE as the free one. It has more information such as time zone compare to peers in the same category. http://lite.ip2location.com

Comment: IPLocate.io provides a free API: [`https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/8.8.8.8`](https://www.iplocate.io/api/lookup/8.8.8.8) - Disclaimer: I run this service.

Comment: Try https://clearip.io
The most elegant one I've seen so far.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

We use Maxmind and it's very good, and pretty accurate.  You can get scenarios where, say, a German company has offices in the US but is using a German IP range for internal purposes.  So, they'll report as Germany while being based in the US.  It won't be 100% reliable.

Comment: Yeah we ended up going with Maxmind in the end. Seems like a good option.

Comment: no, my city listed 5 times,

Comment: You understand a city may have multiple ISPs, or multiple blocks even for a single ISP, right?  It is not an error for your city to be listed 5 times!

Answer (score 79):

Totally free, LGPL, not easily found in google: [ip2c.org](http://ip2c.org)

Comment: This is the best answer and everyone should use this!

Comment: It's being flagged by anti-virus

Comment: Webservice only, so it doesn't allow downloading the database

Comment: Very usefull and easy!

Comment: Also does not support HTTPS.

Comment: It's not accurate for me: It says that I'm in UK but I'm in France. When I'm using Maxmind or ip2location it gives me the right answer.

Comment: The other problem with ip2c is for example, it shows me in "Canada".  As the 2nd biggest country on the planet, just showing "Canada" is.....pretty vague.  Not quite useless, but not great information.

Comment: For tiny projects, this LGPL thing is a nice add-on to this question. However, it's limited. It's unreliable at scale, the location identification is way too simple and thus often inaccurate, and if we're on secure servers (which everyone should be), then the service doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Redzarf: The download of their DB is [here](http://software77.net/geo-ip/). Their [Notes page](http://about.ip2c.org/#notes) mentions which DB they use. It's a bit hard to spot on the downloadpage, you need to look [here](https://i.imgur.com/XjbfVwy.png).

Comment: `You can use http or https.` Stated on their site.

Comment: It doesn't appear that ip2c.org supports ipv6. ipv6 addresses are used pretty frequently. Is there a reliable solution for ipv6 addresses as well? I'd rather an API (like ip2c.org) rather than downloading and maintaining the DB myself.

Comment: As @RobIII points in his comment, the database behind http://i2c.org comes from http://software77.net/geo-ip/, which is the third provider in the original question.

Comment: @joanpau links don’t work now

Comment: @DanielLidström Yes, there is an error in the first link. It should be
https://about.ip2c.org/#licensenotes . And for the second one, it seems that the service is down or no longer there, and the license notes of ip2c have not been updated.

Comment: They stopped getting updated recently