# Geolocation available without asking user's permission

Tags: geolocation, ip-geolocation

Of course, it's possible to get precise [HTML5 geolocation information](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) but this displays a popup in the browser and requires the user's approval:

[image]

**What geolocation solution is available *without asking user's permission*, based on IP, etc. ?**

Comment: We generally don't do "best" questions on Stack Overflow I'm afraid. Googling `Best IP geolocation` pops up a number of good results though, including this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19514749/best-ip-to-country-database

Comment: This question is IP to country. I'm looking for city geolocation instead.

Comment: Maxmind (recommended in the accepted answer) does city-level geolocation and is certainly not a bad bet.