# Is it possible to run code if visitor IP is from a specific country

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to run a this code only if a visitor is from a specific country

`window.onload=function(){
  document.getElementById("buy").click();
};`

I tried this but didn't work :

```
 var requestUrl = "http://ip-api.com/json";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', requestUrl, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.onload = function () {
    var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
    if(json.country == 'France'){
        document.getElementById("buy").click(); 
    };
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: How would you determine the visitor's country?

Comment: This is what im asking for , like use a json link like this one : http://ip-api.com/json and then put rule like if visitor from "germany" run the script and if not just ignore it

Comment: You're asking something different, IMHO.

Comment: @charlietfl i didn't get an answer bro , its like this but this one didn't work :
function Get(http://ip-api.com/json){
 xhr.open('POST', GET, true);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xhr.onload = function () {
     var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
     if (json.country == 'Germany') {
         document.getElementById("buy").click();
     }
 };
 xhr.send(null);

Comment: Hi Aymn, and welcome to StackOverflow. This question looks like it may have been asked before. See if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278024/how-to-detect-browser-country-in-client-site?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @err1100 thanks for your answer but its not im asking for , i've modified the question and may you could understand more thanks

Comment: Are you asking specifically about how to use the `ip-api.com` API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect browser country in client site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278024/how-to-detect-browser-country-in-client-site)

Comment: No , i want that the script i puted work only for visitors from france

Comment: @JackBashford no jack i couldn't find the answer im looking for there , like i said before that little code up there want to run only for visitors from france if from other country just ignore it

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to do it with that same API:

```
fetch('http://ip-api.com/json').then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(data => {
    if (data.country == "France") {
        document.getElementById("buy").click();
    }
});
```

Or if you prefer jQuery:

```
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json", function(data) {
    if (data.country == "France") {
        $("#buy").click();
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this , i tried it but still not worked when the page is load with France IP

Comment: i dont know why maybe there is no window.onload=function(){

Comment: any solution bro