# Get browser user's default currency code, e.g. "AUD"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

ASP.NET:

For a new web visitor, how can we get the default currency that they use?

E.g. if they are browsing from a web browser in Canada, how can we get (in some aspx.vb code) "CAD" so we can display that on page1.aspx?

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: For the record, you won't get that information from the browser. You will need to get the culture for the browser and then map that to a currency code yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no browser API to get the user's currency.

There are various ways of determining the user's location, including IP lookups and the Geolocation API. A full list of options is shown on [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48278549).

You would then need a lookup table to map countries to currencies.

If most of your customers come from one country, it may be easiest to default to that currency and provide a dropdown box for them to change it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user IP address and then detect their country of origin. From the country information, you can display the appropriate currency.

I found one 3rd party site with ASP sample codes (need to modify it to VB.NET).

https://blog.ip2location.com/knowledge-base/display-visitors-country-currency-using-asp-and-ms-sql-database/