# Detecting Users Country with Javascript, and Displaying new div

Tags: javascript

Currently I have the following tag.

```
<a href="<!-- Random Link Here -->" target="_blank">Click Here</a>
```

However when a user visits my website from USA I'd like to show them a different `a href` link than if his friend was to visit my website from another country, how can I go about doing this using only Javascript?

Comment: You can take a look at this answer it will show you how to detect the ip using jquery https://stackoverflow.com/a/35123097/1578983

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect browser country in client site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278024/how-to-detect-browser-country-in-client-site)