# Squarespace Users from Specific Country to URL

Tags: squarespace

Is it possible to have a script in Squarespace header/footer that works for directing users from a specific country to a specific URL?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible.

You can forget about adding a custom server side script, as Squarespace doesn't allow that. reference: https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205815358-Custom-code-FAQ

One option is to use a plugin.

One way to do it isto use a plugin You can do this easily via a plugin called **Geo Targetly** : https://geotargetly.com/squarespace-geo-redirect

Second option is to use JavaScript code:

First, you need to identify the location of the user, answered here: [How to detect browser country in client site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48278024/how-to-detect-browser-country-in-client-site?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Second, use the below script to change the user URL:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  location.replace("https://www.MySite.CA")
}
</script>
```

Comment: Should this work?

`<script language="JavaScript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        if(geoplugin_countryName()=="italy"){
            window.location.replace('https://www.dot.com');
        }
    </script>`